# Is there a way to have visible and hidden responsive elements without duplicating content?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have originally just wanted to pull the nav right only on `xs` and then started separating some css as well.

```
 <ul class="nav-normal hidden-xs pull-right">
     <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Edit</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Archive</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Embed Code</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Customers</a></li>
 </ul>

 <ul class="nav-normal visible-xs">
     <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Edit</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Archive</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Embed Code</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Customers</a></li>
 </ul>

 <style>
    .nav-normal.hidden-xs{
        padding: 25px 20px 0 20px;
    }

    .nav-normal.visible-xs{
        padding: 0px 20px 0 20px;
        li a{
            margin-top:25px
        }
    }
</style>
```

How can I have the same setup without duplicating content? Should I just do a server side include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option for you may be to use the `col-push-*` classes to only push the nav right on certain screen widths..

```
<ul class="nav-normal col-lg-2 col-lg-push-10">
     <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Edit</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Archive</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Embed Code</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Customers</a></li>
</ul>
```

http://bootply.com/89005

Answer (score 0):

You could make php decide what to send to a client. If(statement) { echo 'content1';}else{ echo 'content2';} this should work

Answer (score 0):

Using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) you can inject classes into CSS blocks. Combined with media queries, this can be something worth looking at, If you really need to avoid HTML duplication.

Although, **I'd not recommand that**, as this will make later changes (e.g.: where not only CSS differs) more difficult.

Also note that with duplicated content and `visible-*` classes specified it's obvious, what will be visible on which device even *without reading CSS*. This is a big plus, so I'd consider leaving your code as it is.

**Example**

HTML is very simple, without duplication and has id specified.

```
 <ul class="nav-normal" id="menu">
   <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Edit</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Archive</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Embed Code</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Customers</a></li>
 </ul>
```

LESS file uses media queries and mixins:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #menu{
    padding: 25px 20px 0 20px;
    .pull-right;                 // mixin injected
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #menu{
    padding: 0px 20px 0 20px;
    li a {
        margin-top: 25px;
    }
  }
}
```